# Video API not executing onReady as expected

Tags: javascript, wistia

In the documentation for the wistia JS API, it simply says to call it under the iFrame with the attributed ID and the `_all` flag if you want to hit all videos on the page.

I'm trying to get a basic console log logged with the video API per the docs. The console log doesn't work and the documentation is very poor at explaining why.

I'm following the docs here:

https://wistia.com/support/developers/player-api

This is my code below:

```
<iframe title="Demo4 Video" class="wp-embedded-content" sandbox="allow-scripts" security="restricted" src="https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/zz038smet7?dnt=1#?secret=L8pVNj0787" data-secret="L8pVNj0787" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="640" height="360"></iframe>
            <script src="//fast.wistia.net/assets/external/E-v1.js"></script>
            <script>
            window._wq = window._wq || [];
                _wq.push({ id: "_all", onReady: function(video) {
                console.log("I got a handle to the video!", video);
            }});
          </script>
```

It says directly [in the docs](https://wistia.com/support/developers/player-api#with-iframe-embeds):

> The exact same syntax will work with iframe embeds too:

My iFrame reference match, I'm loading the library `fast.wistia.net/assets/external/E-v1.js` and I'm using the `_all` flag to grab all videos. But I don't see the console log output.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wistia api requires a class of `wistia_embed` on the iFrame to work:

```
<iframe title="Demo4 Video" class="wp-embedded-content wistia_embed" sandbox="allow-scripts" security="restricted" src="https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/zz038smet7?dnt=1#?secret=L8pVNj0787" data-secret="L8pVNj0787" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="640" height="360"></iframe>
        <script src="//fast.wistia.net/assets/external/E-v1.js"></script>
        <script>
        window._wq = window._wq || [];
            _wq.push({ id: "_all", onReady: function(video) {
            console.log("I got a handle to the video!", video);
        }});
      </script>
```